# What is the best platform to build a website like Glassdoor? (Clone like glassdoor)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Am a JavaEE guy. wanted to develop a website just like a glassdoor including the same customer and user reviews for the product. So i googled some and got to know wordpress plays a big role for the same.

Wanted to know will it possible to create a same website template using wordpress or should i need to stick with java cms portal system? (including all the functionality)

Please suggest some templates if its exactly matches glassdoor!! and which one will be best for back end like java or php for this requirement?

Comment: Thanks Kirk...I got struk in the situation where and which framework will adapt for this req. That's the problem statement.  I tried using java but couldn't make review and rating system much effective..

Answer (score 0):

Start using [Bootstrap · The world's most popular mobile-first and responsive front-end framework.](http://getbootstrap.com/) and HTML.

If you want existing themes you can go to

[Free Website Builder | Create a Free Website | WIX.com ,](http://www.wix.com/)

[WordPress.com: Create a free website or blog](https://wordpress.com/)

The Glassdoor website is created in the fbml in my opinion which uses fbml,jquery and javascript.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, wanted to know if its possible through wordpress?

Comment: Yes it is possible through wordpress